# Doubts in the proof that a subgroup $H$ of a Lie group $G$ that is a submanifold of $G$ is (topologically) closed in $G$

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, lie-groups, topological-groups

I am trying to understand the details in the proof of

> Let $G$ be a Lie group, $H $ a subgroup. then
>
> $H$ is a submanifold of $G \implies H$ is closed in $G$

proof:

Since $H$ is a submanifold of $G$, it is in particular a submanifold at the identity $e$.  Then by definition of submanifold there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $e$ and local coordinates $x_i$ on $U$ s.t $U\cap H=\{g \in U:x_{m+1}(g)=...x_n(g)=0 \}$.

$U\cap H= U \cap \overline H \tag 1$.

Take any $g \in \overline H$. Let's prove that  $g \in H$.

$U $ is an open neighborhod of $e$ $\implies gU$ is an open neighborhood  of $g \implies gU \cap H \neq \emptyset$. Let $h \in  gU \cap H $.  Consider the left translation map $l_{g^{-1}}: G \rightarrow G: x \mapsto g^{-1}x$ Then

$g^{-1}h \in U \cap  \overline H H = U \cap \overline H = U \cap H  \tag 2$.

Then $g^{-1}h \in H \implies g \in H$

I am scratching my head about the following things:

1. Why is $(1)$: $U\cap H= U \cap \overline H$ true?  I tried to prove it by double inclusion :$U\cap H \subseteq U \cap \overline H$ is obvious. But I couldn't prove the other one.
2. In $(2)$, why is $g^{-1}h \in U \cap  \overline H H = U \cap \overline H $ ?

$g^{-1}h \in U \cap  \overline H H $ seems to follow from $g^{-1} \in \overline H$ , but I don't see how that can be true.

All I could say is that since $h \in  gU \cap H \implies g^{-1}h= l_{g^{-1}}(h) \in l_{g^{-1}}(gU \cap H)= l_{g^{-1}}(gU)\cap l_{g^{-1}}(H)= U \cap g^{-1}H $, where the next to last equality is because $l_{g^{-1}}$ is bijective

The equality $U \cap  \overline H H = U \cap \overline H$ seems to follow from $ \overline H H = \overline H$, but why is that true?

Comment: $(1)$ is true because inside the open set $U$, elements in $H$ are given by common zeros of continuous functions, so $U \cap H$ is closed in $U$ and hence equals $U \cap \overline{H}$.

Comment: @Zerox Do you mean $U \cap H=\bigcap_{i=m+1}^n x_i^{-1}(\{0\})$ is an intersection of closed sets  and then $\overline {U \cap H}=U \cap H$ ? But I still don't see how that equals $U \cap \overline H$.

Comment: No, I'm not meaning this. I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1)$ is true in the following sense:
Recall that an open set in $U$ is defined to be $V \cap U$ where $V$ is open in $G$. Then because $U$ is open in $G$, $V \cap U$ is also open in $G$. Suppose $g \in U \cap \overline{H}$, then any open neighborhood $V$ of $g$ in $G$ intersects $H$, and $V \cap U$ is also an open neighborhood of $g$ in $G$, so it intersects $H$. Since $V \cap U$ gives every open neighborhood of $g$ in $U$, this means that any open neighborhood of $g$ in $U$ intersects $U \cap H$. Equivalently, $g$ belongs to the closure of $U \cap H$ in $U$.

Because $U \cap H$ is given by the common zeroes of a set of continuous functions in $U$, it is closed in $U$ (**not necessarily closed in $G$!!**). As a result, $g \in U \cap H$, which gives the inclusion $U \cap \overline{H} \subseteq U \cap H$.

$(2)$ is true in the following sense:
For any open neighborhood $V$ of $g^{-1}$, $V^{-1} = \{ v^{-1} \mid v \in V \}$ is open and contains $g$ by the continuity of group inverse on $G$. So $g \in \overline{H} \implies V^{-1} \cap H \ne \emptyset \implies V \cap H^{-1} = V \cap H \ne \emptyset$ for any open neighborhood $V$ of $g^{-1}$, which means $g^{-1} \in \overline{H}$.

Similarly, by the continuity of group product on $G$, $\forall g,h \in G$, the preimage of any open neighborhood $W$ of $gh$ under the product map $G \times G \rightarrow G$ is open. Since $(g,h)$ lies in the preimage of $W$, it has an open neighborhood $U \times V$ inside the preimage where $U,V$ are open in $G$, causing $UV=\{ uv \mid u \in U, v \in V \} \subseteq W$. Suppose $g,h \in \overline{H}$, then for any open neighborhood $W$ of $gh$, there is some open neighborhood $U \ni g$ and $V \ni h$ such that $UV \subseteq W$. But we have $U \cap H \ne \emptyset, V \cap H \ne \emptyset \implies UV \cap H \ne \emptyset$, so $W \cap H \ne \emptyset$ and then $gh \in \overline{H}$. We then conclude that $\overline{H}$ is a supergroup of $H$ and we have $\overline{H}H=\overline{H}$.

Comment: Since you are using sequences, is (1) limited to metric spaces?

Comment: @some_math_guy No, sequence convergence is not limited to metric spaces. A sequence $\{ p_n \}$ converges to $p$ if and only if for every open neighborhood $U$ of $p$, all but finitely many $p_n$'s belong to $U$.

Comment: @Zerox but you cannot characterize the closure of a subset by convergence of sequences in a general topological space. Anyway, this doesn't matter, because manifolds are metrizable. In fact, we only need first-countable to able to work with sequences, and manifolds are even second-countable by definition.

Comment: @LukasHeger I'm afraid the poster is asking for arbitrary Lie groups (even infinite dimensional).

Comment: @Zerox I think you can just replace sequences by nets and then everything still works. Convergent nets characterize the closure in any topological space.

Comment: 1) Why does $U$ being open implies only finitely many $g_n$'s do not belong to $U$?. 2) how can I see  that $U \cap H$ is closed in $U$  and not closed in $G$? Look at the last comment under the post that I edited, why wasn't the intersection correct?

Comment: @LukasHeger I gave a sequence-free proof now.

Comment: What was the problem with the sequence-based proof? Zerox said it was ok becuase manifolds are metrizable. On the other hand, (2) is still using sequences

Comment: @some_math_guy Now the whole proof is free of use of sequences. I avoid sequences because there might be problems in the infinite dimensional cases.

Comment: Regarding 1), I follow it until :"this means that any open neighborhood of $g$ in $U$ intersects $U \cap H$". In symbols:  $(V \cap U) \cap (U \cap H)\neq \emptyset \forall (V \cap U) \in $ the topology over $ U $. After that, I am not sure why $U \cap H$ being closed in U, implies that $g \in U \cap H$

Comment: @some_math_guy This means that in the topology of $U$, $g$ is in the closure of $U \cap H$ in $U$ since any open neighborhood of $g$ in $U$ intersects $U \cap H$. So due to the closedness of $U \cap H$ in $U$, it follows that $g \in U \cap H$.

Comment: A Continuous function as the group inverse does not map open sets to open sets, so why are you arguing that $g^{-1}(V)$ is open? And why is this true $V^{-1} \cap H \ne \emptyset \implies V \cap H^{-1} = V \cap H \ne \emptyset$? How did you get to that from $V^{-1}\cap H \neq \emptyset$? I don't know how you past the $(.)^{-1}$ to the other set

Comment: @some_math_guy Group inverse is the inverse of itself, so it is an open map (in fact it is a self homeomorphism). And $V \cap H^{-1}=(V^{-1} \cap H)^{-1}$.

Comment: How can i do that with sets?

Comment: @some_math_guy I think I have defined what an inverse of a set is in my answer. $V^{-1} = \{ v^{-1} \mid v \in V \}$ works for arbitrary subset of $G$, not just open set. So the meaning of $V \cap H^{-1}=(V^{-1} \cap H)^{-1}$ is very clear. And if $V^{-1} \cap H$ is non-empty, its inverse will be non-empty too.

Comment: OK, but $V \cap H^{-1} = V \cap H$? Are you implying that $H^{-1}=H$?

Comment: "$\overline{H}$ is a supergroup of $H$" Ok, but how does that imply that "we have $\overline{H}H=\overline{H}$."?. It basically says that if I multiply all the elements of a group by those of a subgroup I get the same group. uhmmm, for sure the elements will be in the grop, but how come I obtain exactly the group?

Comment: @some_math_guy $H$ is a group, so $H = H^{-1}$. $\overline{H} H = \{ gh \mid g \in \overline{H}, h \in H \}$ contains $\{ g \cdot e \mid g \in \overline{H} \} = \overline{H}$ so is the whole group.